# How to change Folder Creation shortcut in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, directory, 19.04, plasma-5

I am using Kubuntu for a long time but today when I tried to create a folder using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> nothing happened and then I realised the shortcut is <kbd>F10</kbd> in KDE Plasma. I tried to change it but I was not able to find any option in global or standard shortcut settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Dolphin.

In *Settings*, click on *Configure Shortcuts…*. (Alternatively, if you have the *Control* icon (☰) instead of the conventional menu, click on it and then on *Configure Shortcuts…*.)

In there, scroll down till you find *Create Folder…*. You'll see *F10* as the shortcut and possibly a blank space next to *>* in the *Alternate* column.

[image]

Click in the marked area and you'll get something like this:

[image]

Click on *None* (or whatever else is there) and then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> if that's the shortcut you want. You may see a pop-up indicating that the shortcut may already be in use. Just click Reassign and then on <kbd>OK</kbd>.

That should now allow you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new folder in Dolphin.

Comment: Thank you very much,will this change the shortcut through out the kde desktop?

Comment: So it is not possible to add a new global shortcut for folder creation in kde :/

Comment: Can you please clarify the context? Do you want to create a folder when in Dolphin or do you want to use the same shortcut to create a new folder on the desktop? Or how do you plan to use the shortcut "through out the kde desktop"?

Comment: I want to create the folder at both places - inside Dolphin and on the desktop.

Comment: If you create it in Dolphin in the ~/Desktop folder it will also appear on your Desktop. To directly create folders on the Desktop, right-click on a blank area on your Desktop and you'll see a "Create New" item in the context menu. That will allow you to create a new folder or a new text file on the Desktop.

Comment: Okay thanks man,I think the F10 shortcut will work on desktop to.